# How to get flexbox behavior COMBINED with bootstrap columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

**Problem:** I can't get Bootstrap's responsive columns to have the same height.

**Solution:** Stack Overflow's we-code-while-you-wait service will provide it. ;)

**Setup:**

My problem is that I'm using bootstraps responsive columns like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths">
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths">
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths">
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths">
         ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xxs-12 col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-5ths col-lg-5ths">
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

so that they will take up different percentage-based widths at different screensizes, e.g. the difference between what you see below

[image]

[image]

and you can see that I've detailed in the second image the common problem I have. The fix is to force all the responsive columns to have the same height.

I know how to use flexbox to make siblings `div`s have the same height when they are in the same row, but this screws up when applied to Boostrap columns.

Pic of what happens when screen contracts after applying `flex:1` to Bootstrap responsive columns and `display:flex` to their parent:

[image]

Is there solution that doesn't use JavaScript?

Comment: If you simply want the **Business Strategy** box to be in a new row you can separate your `col-*` into `div.row`

Comment: @TasosK. But then that makes it on a new row when the screen is at its maximum width.

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fo5o8n8y/1/

just add a class to the columns you want to be the same size and add this css to them:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
}
```